# Transactions and prepared statements in Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, transactions, android-sqlite, prepared-statement

I'm using Android 5.1 and SQLite database. I have the following prepared statement and transaction:

```
String stringValue = "hello";
try {

    String sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (column_1, column_2) VALUES (?, ?)";
    SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement(sql);
    db.beginTransaction();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        statement.clearBindings();
        statement.bindLong(1, i);
        statement.bindString(2, stringValue + i);
        statement.executeInsert();
    }

    db.setTransactionSuccessful(); // This commits the transaction if there were no exceptions

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.w("Exception:", e);
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

This does not work. Does not work means that `statement.executeInsert();` blocks, i.e. there is no exception or error but it just stalls forever. When I first start the transaction and then compile the prepared statement it works, i.e. `statement.executeInsert();` is executed and returns very fast.

Why does this not work and is there no possibility to only compile the prepared statement once and not for every transaction.

Comment: Please edit your question and explain, **in detail**, what "This does not work" means and what "it works" means. You might also consider just using the `insert()` method on `SQLiteDatabase`, instead of a `SQLiteStatement`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have made an edit.